# Raster: Calculation on RasterStack only if not NA in other RasterLayer

Tags: r, if-statement, r-raster

I have a `RasterStack` `s1` consisting of 400 layers with data from an island. The extent of the raster is cropped to the extent of the island, but due to its irregular shape, only around 20% of the pixels are actually land area and have data values; the other 80% are water and `NA`.

I also have a land-water-mask `lwm` (`RasterLayer`), where land is coded as 1 and water as `NA`.

I would like to do different kinds of cell-based calculations on `s1`, but noticed that these take a long time to finish. To speed things up, the calculations should only be carried out for cells that are land area, whereas water areas should always be `NA`. In pseudo-code:

```
for each cell:
    if cell is land
        do calculation
    if cell is water
        return(NA)
```

An requirement is `memory-safety`.

Here is some sample data to illustrate the problem:

```
library(raster)
# generate data
lwm <- raster(nrow = 5, ncol = 5)
lwm[] <- c(rep(NA, 10), rep(1, 5), rep(NA, 10))

r1 <- raster(nrow = 5, ncol = 5)
r1[] <- runif(ncell(r1)) * 10
r2 <- raster(nrow = 5, ncol = 5)
r2[] <- runif(ncell(r2)) * 10
s1 <- stack(r1, r2)
s1 <- mask(s1, lwm)

# this works, but all NA-values on water are also unnecessarily evaluated 
calc(s1, function(x) {sum(!is.na(x))})
```

Comment: In this conditions, maybe it could be better to identify the indexes of the non-NA cells, extract only those pixels from the raster, do the calculation and then put the results "back" in a new raster.

Comment: Would this approach be memory-safe? In my opinion, this wouldn't be the case for a very large `RasterStack`, would it?

Comment: No, that would be not memory friendly for very large rasters (unless your "good data" area is very small).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some playing around, I finally found a solution which works very well in my case, and which takes off quite a nice amount from the overall processing time:

```
library(raster)
# generate data
lwm <- raster(nrow = 50, ncol = 50)
lwm[] <- 1

# replace 80% with NA values
lwm[sample(1:ncell(lwm), round(0.8 * ncell(lwm)))] <- NA

r1 <- raster(lwm)
r1[] <- runif(ncell(r1)) 
r1_list <- replicate(400 , r1)
s1 <- stack(r1_list)
s1 <- mask(s1, lwm)

# this works, but all NA-values on water are also unnecessarily evaluated 
system.time(r_sum1 <- calc(s1, function(x) {sum(x)}))
#user  system elapsed 
#0.14    0.00    0.14 

## new approach:

# stack land-water-mask with RasterStack 
s1_lwm <- stack(lwm, s1)

# function to check if first element of vector is NA; if yes, return NA; if no, do calculation
fun1 <- function(y) {
  if (!is.na(y[1])) {
    y = y[-1]
    return(sum(y))
  } else {
      return(NA)
    }
}

system.time(
  r_sum2 <- calc(s1_lwm, fun = fun1)
)
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.4     0.0     0.4 

# results are identical 
identical(r_sum1[], r_sum2[])
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a tricky one and unfortunetely I don't have a straight forward solution for you.

You can either do multiple crops of the island (i.e. 2-3) to minimise NA values and do the calculcations separately on each cropped raster and mosaic the results.

Or another option is to do a parallel calculation, which will speed up the process significantly:

```
  #initialize cluster
  #number of cores to use for clusterR function (max recommended: ncores - 1)
  beginCluster(3)

  #calculation
  result <- clusterR(s1, calc, args=list(fun=function(x) {sum(!is.na(x))}))

  #end cluster
  endCluster()
```

Since you asked for a memory-safe solution, you should look how much RAM is being allocated when you only a singe core and then estimate how many cores you can run your calculation on, so you won't run out of memory.

Good luck! Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! :) 
I should have mentioned that I already use parallel calculation, and that I was searching for a solution which could be combined with `clusteR`.

Comment: The idea with multiple crops of the island is good, but there would be quite some pre-processing and post-processing involved (which I was hoping to avoid).